# How to speed up VS2008 with Resharper startup?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

There is no doubt that the VS2008 startup time is more than doubled when Resharper is installed.

Has anyone found any way to mitigate Resharper's penalty at least a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use an SSD drive or really fast disk drive. I don't have one though :-(

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to [ReSharper 4.5 Nightly Builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds) because they are supposed to be better at performance and mean on memory consumption

Comment: Thanks, but I've been hearing that since version 2.

Comment: Well, it made a difference for me

Comment: I really does make a difference, 4.5 is noticeably faster than 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Vista Ultimate 64 bit, Intel quad core machine with 8GB of RAM to speed it up. :-)

Probably more RAM would improve the speed. How much do you have now?

I have used Resharper on a dual core with 2GB of RAM, and I could definitely tell there was a slowdown.

I can see no noticeable performance hit on my current machine though.

Comment: i have 3gb on a xp32 box.  Memory is not an issue, I never hit the upper limit, so adding more won't help.